# PhoneGap sql checking for duplicates

Tags: sql, forms, cordova, duplicates

I want to input a query to check the database for duplicate when inserting data into the database so it would prevent the activity Name from being entered more than once in a database

```
    function insertQueryDB(tx) {
    var myDB = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataEntryTb (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, activityName TEXT NOT NULL, location TEXT NOT NULL, time NOT NULL, date NOT NULL, reporter NOT NULL)');
        var an = document.forms["myForm"]["activityName"].value;
        var l = document.forms["myForm"]["location"].value;
        var t = document.forms["myForm"]["time"].value;
        var d = document.forms["myForm"]["date"].value;
        var r = document.forms["myForm"]["reporter"].value;
        var query = 'INSERT INTO dataEntryTb ( activityName, location, time, date, reporter) VALUES ( "'+an+'", "'+l+'", "'+t+'", "'+d+'", "'+r+'")';

        navigator.notification.alert("Retrieved the following: Activity Name="+an+" and Location="+l);
        tx.executeSql(query,[]);
    }``
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Create the table with name being `unique`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataEntryTb (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    activityName TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    location TEXT NOT NULL,
    time NOT NULL, date NOT NULL,
    reporter NOT NULL
);
```

Then the database will return an error if the name is already in the table.

Comment: I want to be able to make the user knows that it has an error when inserting the value into the form letting them know the activity name already exists

Comment: @lifeishard . . . Just catch the error when the `insert` fails.